# SSDT and vstest capability missing in container when installing Visual Studio Build Tools

Tags: docker, azure-pipelines, build-tools

Following [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/build-tools-container?view=vs-2019#create-and-build-the-dockerfile) I installed the Build Tools into the container using the `--all` option.

Additionally I am installing the [Azure Pipelines Agent service into the container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/docker?view=azure-devops) on start-up.

Now I have 2 problems:

- The scanning part of the Azure Pipelines agent which detects the capabilities, does not find/add the "vstest" capability but it seems to be there as I do find the `vstest.console.exe` within the container. Any ideas what may be missing or why it is not detected correctly?
- SSDT has not been installed. Searched for it in the container - nothing. How could this be when `--all` is being used? It should be part of the package, as it shows the data workloads in the install wizard. `##[error]The nuget command failed with exit code(1) and error(C:\azp\agent\_work\2\s\src\Something.Database\Something.Database.sqlproj(52,57): error MSB4226: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\SSDT\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets" was not found. Also, tried to find "Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\SSDT\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets" in the fallback search path(s) for $(MSBuildExtensionsPath) - "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild" . These search paths are defined in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\msbuild.exe.Config". Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk in one of the search paths.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I went into [this direction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41278108/is-it-possible-to-install-visual-studio-in-a-windows-container/46364697), so I used [this `Dockerfile`](https://github.com/lukas-lansky/visual-studio-docker-build/blob/master/vs.Dockerfile) by `lukas-lansky` as a starting point.

As I already mentioned I added the [Azure Pipelines Agent part](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/docker?view=azure-devops) on top of it.

As I needed to build a full solution with Web Deploy packaging, including database projects (SSDT) and had to run tests, I needed to adjust `lukas-lansky`s command line call to `vs_community.exe` slightly:

```
RUN & "$env:TEMP\vs_community.exe" --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetWeb --includeRecommended --quiet --wait --norestart --noUpdateInstaller | Out-Default
```

You have to know that only **Required** components of a workload (ID) are installed by default. Workload and component IDs supported by the installer are documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/workload-component-id-vs-community?view=vs-2019). Because of this behavior Web Deploy was missing. So I added the `--includeRecommended` option to bring in Web Deploy.

Answer (score 1):

> what may be missing or why it is not detected correctly?

Since not know too much on your self-agent's configuration, and in fact, the task does not consider the capability value, it will attempt to find the tool automatically.

You could add some scripts manually to make it be detected.

Just go the `bin` file of your agent, then add a file named `Add-VisualStudioTestCapabilities.ps1` under `powershell` folder:*(Please **replace** its corresponding path on your side)*

[image]

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param()

if (Test-Path ":\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow") {
    Write-Capability -Name 'VSTest' -Value ":\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow"
}
```

And restart the agent.

---

> error MSB4226: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   Visual
>   Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\SSDT\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets"
>   was not found

This is a very normal message when SSDT does not exists.

See this [blog](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-integration-services/new-delivery-model-for-sql-server-data-tools-in-visual-studio/bc-p/963770/highlight/true#M578).

> **SSDT** only support VS Community, Professional and Enterprise. VS Build Tools lacks some necessary components.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed insights. I will try those out. It's really weird that the Build Tools do not deliver the necessary stuff. There is even an option in the GUI installer called "SQL Server Data Tools: Buildtools", but obviously the "Buildtools" variant is lacking some of the components as you mentioned.

Comment: As the image was based on `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019` the "Test Agent" was installed. This tooling (and the `vstest.console.exe` sits inside `Microsoft Visual Studio\TestAgent\...\TestWindow`. This path is not incorporated in the scanning process. Using your approach I did it manually. But weird error message were shown during build. There also seem some components missing to execute tests. Because of this **and** your answer regarding SSDT, I have chosen another direction which I will document in another answer.

Comment: Thank you again for the insights regarding the capability scanning process. This was an interesting journey for me.

Comment: @timmkrause It’s welcome! Pity for bring another error to you, but still awesome to know you got the guide finally:-)